# Is it correct to write a cron job like this?

Tags: cron

I want to perform the first five days of each month and the last five days of each month.Is this written correctly?

```
0 7 24-31,1-5 * * [ `date -d "+ 5 day" +\%e` -le 5 -o `date +\%e` -le 5 ] && /usr/local/bin/php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your single entry won't work because months have different numbers of days. You need multiple entries in the crontab:

```
0 7 1-5 * * [ date -d "+ 5 day" +\%e -le 5 -o date +\%e -le 5 ] && /usr/local/bin/php
0 7 27-31 1,3,5,7,8,10,12 * [ date -d "+ 5 day" +\%e -le 5 -o date +\%e -le 5 ] && /usr/local/bin/php
0 7 26-30 4,6,9,11 * [ date -d "+ 5 day" +\%e -le 5 -o date +\%e -le 5 ] && /usr/local/bin/php
0 7 24-28 2 * [ date -d "+ 5 day" +\%e -le 5 -o date +\%e -le 5 ] && /usr/local/bin/php
```

Needs a bit more thought to handle leap years.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I feel that this is a bit cumbersome. I have considered the leap year, so the last five days are from the 24th. I rely on the judgment to confirm the last five days of each month and before each month. Five days, what I am worried about is the "24-31, 1-5" date syntax.

Comment: Your version will actually run on the last eight days of Jan, Mar, May, Jul, Aug, Oct and Dec; the last seven days of Apr, Jun, Sep and Nov; and the last five or six days of February, depending on leap year. So, my version might be 'cumbersome' but at least it does what you said you want to do.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your suggestion, I will try both ways.